# Getting the Bluetooth version of a device

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, bluetooth, windows-10

I need validate that a Bluetooth LE 5.0 device is connected to a computer. I have been reviewing all the properties I can query for a device but I haven't found one that contains the Bluetooth version of the device. Can this be done using UWP or any other method?

This is the code I am using to explore the data I can get using UWP:

```
string aqsFilter = "System.Devices.DevObjectType:=5 AND (System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{BB7BB05E-5972-42B5-94FC-76EAA7084D49}\" OR System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{E0CBF06C-CD8B-4647-BB8A-263B43F0F974}\") AND (System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True OR System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.IssueInquiry:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#False)";
        string[] requestedProperties = {
            "System.Devices.Aep.Category",
            "System.DeviceInterface.Bluetooth.DeviceAddress",
            "System.DeviceInterface.Bluetooth.Flags",
            "System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.Le.AddressType",
            "System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.Le.Appearance",
            "System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.Le.Appearance.Category",
            "System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.Le.Appearance.Subcategory",
            "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress",
            "System.Devices.AepService.ServiceClassId",
            "System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId",
            "System.Devices.AepService.ProtocolId"
        };
        DeviceInformationCollection ConnectedBluetoothDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqsFilter, requestedProperties); //aqsFilter

        foreach (DeviceInformation connectedBluetoothDevice in ConnectedBluetoothDevices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(connectedBluetoothDevice.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("  " + connectedBluetoothDevice.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("  " + connectedBluetoothDevice.Kind.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("  " + connectedBluetoothDevice.Properties.Count);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> property in connectedBluetoothDevice.Properties)
            {
                if (property.Value != null && property.Value.GetType().IsArray)
                {
                    String[] array = (String[])property.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine("    " + property.Key + " = " + array[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("    " + property.Key + " = " + property.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the `System.DeviceInterface.Bluetooth.ProductVersion` property the one you are looking for?

Comment: That property is coming empty for both a Bluetooth mouse and a Bluetooth speaker

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the device that you are using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft's RJN-00025. I also temporarily modified the filter to also detect regular BT (not LE) devices to also list the properties of a Bose SoundLink speaker. For both devices the property `System.DeviceInterface.Bluetooth.ProductVersion` is empty.

I went through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/devices-bumper) list of properties and I couldn't find one that contains the information I need. There is one that might, but I couldn't find information on how to interpret it: `System.DeviceInterface.Bluetooth.Flags`

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, most properties come up empty for a paired device